# Reading the ID of an Node in XML-File using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem with reading variables inside of an XML-file in C#.

I have the following XML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<list xmlns:xsd=...> 
    <row id="2b7bed1a-bd72-4e83-9b69-26c05cce6379">
        <hostname>TestName1</hostname> 
        <outputs> 
            <outputId>HL7 Output</outputId> 
        </outputs> 
    </row>
    
    <row ...

    </row>
</list>
```

I m trying here to write a code, which reads the XML-File and with use of a loop get the id of each hostname.

I already wrote the following part, which loads the xml-file. Can someone help me to complete this?

```
   var xmlFile = @"C:\Users\vosoughi-m\Desktop\output_mapping.xml";
   var doc = new XmlDocument();
   doc.Load(xmlFile);
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

I Would like to have the following output:

Hostname: TestName1

ID: 2b7bed1a-hd72-4e83-9b69-66c05cce6379

---

Hostname: TestName2

ID: ce4372d3-453e-4ed8-ba60-6694a2680c24

...

Comment: What problem are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication21
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Descendants("row")
                .Select(x => new { id = (string)x.Attribute("id"), hostname = (string)x.Element("hostname") }).ToList();
        }
 
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Can also create a dictionary to make look up easy.